# Alt text for Unicode/Emojis in HTML/CSS without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I want to detect a situation when browser displays a placeholder (▯, �, etc)  instead of  a Unicode character, say ⏻. Either browser does not support font fallback, or a font that supports a character is not installed. I would like to replace the unsupported character with alt text, similar to `<img>` tag. For ⏻ it would be something like "Turn on/off" or "Power button".

Is there a way to do so in HTML and CSS without JavaScript?

Comment: _“a font that supports a character is not installed”_ - I doubt there is a trivial way to check this. Plus, it would be approaching accessibility the wrong way to begin with, IMHO. Whether the user might be able to determine what some more or less randomly chosen icon means, does not always depend on just whether a specific font could be loaded and applied successfully. So that textual information should ideally be present to begin with, at least in the form of a title attribute or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the following answer and adapt it to modern browsers:

[Detecting individual Unicode character support with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911000/detecting-individual-unicode-character-support-with-javascript#answer-13207053)